# Express number of partitions into prime numbers using partitions into natural numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion, integer-partitions

Let $P(n)$ is number of partitions of $n$ into natural numbers.
$R(n)$ is number of partitions of $n$ into prime numbers.

> Is there any expression that relates $P(n)$ , and $R(n)$? I look for something that looks like this: $R(n) = f(P(n))$, for some function $f$.

Here is what have i done.

Consider two generating functions:

$$G(x) := \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^n} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}P(n)x^n$$
$$F(x): = \prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{1-x^p}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}R(n)x^n$$.

I was trying to apply inclusion-exclusion formula to find connection between $G$ and $F$. For example $$\frac{(1-x)G(x)}{F(x)}=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus(\{1\}\cup \mathbb{P})}\frac{1}{1-x^n}$$ And this is related to the number of partitions into composite numbers.

Thank you in advance for any help.